# Is there a webUI that lets me see the query execution plan in MemSQL?

Tags: singlestore

```
memsql>show plancache;
```

Is there a equivalent exists in the form of a web UI? This would be useful for the users who do not have access to command line.

Currently the command line output is not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next memsql release (tentatively MemSQL 4.5) will have more readable EXPLAIN command line output. Visualizing the explain output is a highly requested feature and will make it into a feature release.

If your after more readable plancache output, you can use information_schema.plancache.  For example to see the most expensive queries you've executed run:

```
SELECT EXECUTION_TIME/COMMITS, QUERY_TEXT from information_schema.PLANCACHE
ORDER BY EXECUTION_TIME/COMMITS DESC LIMIT 5
```